# How to iterate a json object in python to populate database with each item

Tags: python, json

I would like to iterate over the below shown json via python in order to populate each item in the object to my db:

```
[{
    'description': 'DP WORLD',
    'displaySymbol': '3DW.HM',
    'symbol': '3DW.HM'
}, {
    'description': 'SPDR Series Trust - SPDR S&P 600 Small Cap Value ETF',
    'displaySymbol': '4JZ3.HM',
    'symbol': '4JZ3.HM'
}, {
    'description': 'DGH Deutsche Grundwert Holding AG',
    'displaySymbol': '5TR.HM',
    'symbol': '5TR.HM'
}, { 

    [...]

}]
```

Here is my approach:

```
def getStocksAvailable:
    exchangeHamburg = (requests.get('https://....').json())

    for item in exchangeHamburg:
            print(item[0])
            print(item[1])
            print(item[2])

    # push to DB logic

getStocksAvailable();
```

which throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/CFD/CFD/feeder/feeder.py", line 24, in <module>
    getStocksAvailable();
  File "C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/CFD/CFD/feeder/feeder.py", line 20, in getStocksAvailable
    print(item[0])
KeyError: 0
```

### Updated with the comments made, throws new error now

Comment: you obviously receive a `dict` and not a `list`, so the data is not what you present. Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: A general advice: if you want quick help, create a copy&pasteable MWE.

Comment: I got it, the brackts were the issue. Can be closed... thanks!

Comment: What a chaos...

Comment: @tamasgal yeah, enough of this. Closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries have named elements, not numbered. So it should be

```
        print(item['description'])
        print(item['displaySymbol'])
        print(item['symbol'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You know which keys comes from that dict. Due to its structure, dict values is simple to call so:

```
for item in exchangeHamburg:
    print(item.get('description', 'default value'))
```

notice that .get method search for key "description" and then return its value, or return "default value" from second parameter (without second parameter it returns None).